# Filling blanks with fixed rule

Tags: word, enigmatic-puzzle, wordplay

> Her favorite fruits are lemons and _____________.
>
> He drove his car to _______________.
>
> He rode a horse along the ______________.
>
> When I eat ____________, I get a smile on my face.
>
> Take ____________ while driving a race car.
>
> Rose thorns can make your finger _____________.
>
> Every time you visit Rome, you find _____________ to do.
>
> My uncle is a ______________ and wears a purple robe.
>
> On ______________, we'll drive a five-seater car.
>
> 'Finders keepers', she said to her __________________.
>
> The men in the manors were held for _______________.
>
> Witches have _______________ when making potions.
>
> She ate it and then ______________ that it tasted funny.
>
> Wait in the kitchen for the sauce to _______________.

There is a single rule used to fill all the above blanks. What is it?

**Notes**
1. This is my first such word puzzle. Hope you like it.
2. Each blank has one word. The length of the blank has nothing to do with the length of the words.
3. I can't think of a good title that does not reveal the answer.
4. There is no math or encryption involved.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The rule is

> Each word is an anagram of another word in the sentence.

---

Her favorite fruits are lemons and _____________.

> MELONS

He drove his car to _______________.

> DOVER

He rode a horse along the ______________.

> SHORE

When I eat ____________, I get a smile on my face.

> LIMES

Take ____________ while driving a race car.

> CARE

Rose thorns can make your finger _____________.

> SORE

Every time you visit Rome, you find _____________ to do.

> MORE

My uncle is a ______________ and wears a purple robe.

> BORE (thanks, @alexmc!)

On ______________, we'll drive a five-seater car.

> EASTER

'Finders keepers', she said to her __________________.

> FRIENDS

The men in the manors were held for _______________.

> RANSOM

Witches have _______________ when making potions.

> OPTIONS

She ate it and then ______________ that it tasted funny.

> STATED

Wait in the kitchen for the sauce to _______________.

> THICKEN

Comment: My uncle is a bore?

Comment: Yeah, maybe...but why purple?

Comment: @alexmc is right. That was really fast. Is the puzzle really that easy?

Comment: @ghosts_in_the_code my brain anagrams things devilishly quickly. I saw "lemon" and immediately thought of melons, and when it fit into the blank I ran with it. :) I liked the puzzle a lot!

Comment: It was a good puzzle, would have lasted longer if the queen of anagrams hadn't seen it so soon :)